# Print WinForms TextBox with Tab Formatting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formatting, textbox, tabs

I have been working on some code that prints a textbox that lists contact information. When I try to print it, it doesn't print out the tabs that I used to format the text. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs) _
Handles prndoc.PrintPage

    Dim fnt As Font = resultTextBox.Font
    ev.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

    Dim area As SizeF = New SizeF(ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height)
    Dim lines, chars As Integer
    ev.Graphics.MeasureString(resultTextBox.Text.Substring(mStringPos), fnt, _
                              area, StringFormat.GenericTypographic, chars, _
                              lines)

    Dim rc As New RectangleF(ev.MarginBounds.Left, ev.MarginBounds.Top, _ 
                             ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height)
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(resultTextBox.Text.Substring(mStringPos, chars), _
                           fnt, Brushes.Black, rc, _
                           StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

    mStringPos += chars

    ev.HasMorePages = mStringPos < resultTextBox.Text.Length
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The main thing you did wrong is not tell us what the problem is. "It doesn't print out the tabs", but what _does_ it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you do this?

```
Dim fmt as StringFormat
fmt = StringFormat.GenericTypographic
fmt.SetTabStops( -- put something here --  )
ev.Graphics.DrawString(resultTextBox.Text.Substring(mStringPos, chars), _
                           fnt, Brushes.Black, rc, _
                           fmt)
```

Does that change things?  (Check my syntax - I don't typically do VB.)